# How to put things from a textfield into an integer array in java

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a program I am trying to put into a GUI and I have no Idea how to get something that a user puts into the textfield into an array
    Here is my code so far:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GUIMain extends JFrame{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static JLabel label3;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static JLabel label2;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static JLabel label4;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static JLabel label;
    private static JTextField text;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static int [] array={98,99,100};
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public GUIMain(){
        super("Math Converter");
        //this.array = array;
        Arrays.sort(array);
        //System.out.println("The median is : "+median(array));//prints Median
        //System.out.println("The mode is : "+mode(array));//prints Mode
        //System.out.println("The mean is : "+mean(array));//prints the mean
        //pack();
        setSize(600,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(true);
        setVisible(true);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10,10,10));//
        JTextField text = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(toStringMedian(array));
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel(toStringMode(array));
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel(toStringMean(array));

        JLabel label4 = new JLabel("How many numbers do you wan't in your array?");
        Container content = getContentPane();
        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
        layout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        add(panel1);
        content.setLayout(layout);
        content.add(panel);
        content.add(panel1);
        content.add(panel2);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,2,10,10));//10,2,10,10
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,1,10));//1,2,1,10
        panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4,10,10));//1,4,10,10
        panel.add(label4);
        panel.add(text);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(label2);
        panel.add(label3);
        text.addActionListener(new Action());
        JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menu);
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        menu.add(file);
        JMenu Help = new JMenu("Help");
        menu.add(Help);
        JMenuItem About = new JMenuItem("About");
        Help.add(About);
        JMenuItem Exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        file.add(Exit);
        Exit.addActionListener(new Exit());
        this.label = label;
        this.label2 = label2;
        this.label3 = label3;
        this.label4 = label4;
        this.text = text;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new GUIMain();
    }

    public static int mode(int[] a) {
        int previous = a[0];//sets previous to array at 0
        int popular = a[0];//Initializes popular
        int count = 1;//initializes count
        int maxCount = 1;//initializes max count

        for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {//goes through the array
            if (a[i] == previous)//tests to see if array at i is equal to previous 
                count++;//adds one every time this is true

            else {//if not then it will go through the next statement
                if (count > maxCount) {//tests to see if count is greater than max count
                    popular = a[i-1];//sets popular to a at i-1
                    maxCount = count;//sets max count to count
                }
                previous = a[i];//sets previous to a at i
                count = 1;//sets count to one when finished then it goes through the loop again
            }
        }
        return count > maxCount ? a[a.length-1] : popular;//returns only if count is greater than max count the integer popular
    }
    public static int median(int[] a){
        int median= 0 ;//declares median
        if(a.length%2==0)//tests to see if the length of the array is even 
            median = (a[(int)a.length/2] + (int)a[a.length/2+1])/2;//if it is even then it takes the averages of the two numbers in the middle
        else{
            median = a[a.length/2];//finds the number in the middle of the array
        }
        return median;//returns the value of median
    }
    public static int mean(int[]a){
        int mean = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<a.length;i++){
            mean =(int)(a[i]+a [i]-1)/a.length;//finds the average of the elements of the array
        }
        return mean;//returns the value of mean
    }
    public static String toStringMedian(int[]a){
        return"This is the Median : "+median(a);
    }
    public static String toStringMean(int[]a){
        return"This is the Mean : "+mean(a);
    }
    public static String toStringMode(int[]a){
        return"This is the Mode : "+median(a);
    }

    static class Exit implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
    static class Action implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            int z = 0;
            if(e.getSource()==text){

            }
        }
    }
 }
```

I have tried to change it before with something like this int Input = Integer.parseInt(text.getText()); but that takes too long is there another way?

Comment: `textField.getText().toString()`. Just google it

Comment: No I mean from what ever the user inputs into a Integer into an array that gets the median mean and mode I already have the median mean and mode down I just wan't to get user input from the Jtextfield

Comment: WAY too much code included. Take out the irrelevant parts, which is pretty much everything except for two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may take too long, but there is basically no other way to turn a user's text field input into an integer that you can perform calculations on.

```
int input = Integer.parseInt(text.getText());
```

This code will give you a single integer from a text string that the user typed in.

Comment: Just to be picky, you shouldn't capitalize the first letter of your variable name. Hence the reason it's colouring `Input`.

Comment: Of course, you are correct.  I merely copied his code.  Correction made to reflect accepted convention.